# PdfPtable Shrink to Page

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext

I am currently working with a `PdfPtable` and everything is fine so far - but I have one annoying problem: sometimes a table is higher than a page, the `PDFPtable` then breaks and some rows are on the next page.

Unfortunately, I am currently modelling a piece of older software who simply shrinks the table until it fits to one page. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this behaviour?

In short: Is there a way to keep a table on one page? Shrinking the table instead of splitting the table.

Very simple code so far:

```vb
Dim Mytables as List(Of DataTables)           
Dim doc As Document = Nothing            

doc = New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Dim pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(PDFPath, FileMode.Create))
pdfw.SetFullCompression()
pdfw.CloseStream = True
mywriter = pdfw

for i=0 to myTables.count-1 

   Dim Table = New PdfPTable(myTables(i).Columns.Count) 

   Here comes a huge chunk of business logic. 
   doc.add(table)
   Doc.NewPage()
next.
```

I have tried `table.keeptogether=true` and `Table.SplitLate = True`, with no effect.

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Comment: @Nudier: The code is very simple:
basically
for i=0 to myTables.count-1
 Dim Table = New PdfPTable(myTables(i).Columns.Count)
 Here comes a huge chunk of business logic.
next.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the properties for the tables added to the document

```
//The code below creates a 2x2 table
Dim Table = New PdfPTable(2) 
Table.HorizontalAlignment = 0  //0=Left, 1=Center, 2=Right
Table.SpacingBefore = 10
Table.SpacingAfter = 10
Table.DefaultCell.Border = 0
Table.SetWidths(New Integer() { 1, 4 })
Table.AddCell(New Phrase("Content1"))
Table.AddCell(New Phrase("Content 2"))

Here comes a huge chunk of business logic. 
 doc.add(table)
 doc.NewPage()
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hello Nudier,excuse my late answer - I was ill :(
Unfortunately this does not work.
This creates a simple table - but if the table has enough rows, it still "spills over" to the next page.